# How to handle advanced standard authentication model in Django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

There is my simplified user model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BasePerson(models.Model):
    account = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    patronymic_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    dob = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Performer(BasePerson):
    additional_performer_info = models.TextField(max_length=200)


class Director(BasePerson):
    additional_director_info = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

It uses standard User class, as Django documentation advices, linked with additional info about users. 
There is my class for creating `User`, how to complete my code to create Performer or Director afterward? I think I should user `success_url`, but don't know how.

```
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegisterAccountFormView(FormView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm

    template_name = "accounts/registration.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_user = form.save()
        return super(RegisterAccountFormView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this question. Where is the data for the new Performer/Directory instance coming from?

Comment: It is info about them. It it is just example, but there will be many other fields - filled by Performer or Director himself.

Comment: But do you have a form and a view where the user can enter that data?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, no, there are a lot of form classes in Django, I just do not know which to choose: CreateView, just Form or something else

Comment: and how to link them to just created User